# save return-value of javascript in robotframework selenium2library gives 0

Tags: javascript, selenium, extjs, robotframework, return-value

What I'd like to do is to click all the links on a page and close the upcoming tabs. They are located as:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href=#>random text</a>
   </li>
   <li>...
```

As there are many links to click, I tried something like:

```
Click All Links
    Set Global Variable    ${i}    1
    ${elementCount}=    Execute Javascript    return document.querySelectorAll('a').length
    FOR    ${i}   IN RANGE    ${elementCount}
        Execute Javascript    document.getElementsByTagName('a')[i].click();
        Run Keyword and Ignore Error    Delete Tab
        Exit For Loop If    ${i} == elementCount
    END
    Log    Exited


Delete Tab
    Sleep    ${Delay_short}
    ${title_var}    Get Window Titles
    Select Window    title=${title_var}[1]
    Close Window
```

But I cannot work past the first return length, as ${elementCount} is always shown with value 0:

```
Executing JavaScript:
return document.querySelectorAll('a').length
Without any arguments.
20210104 10:20:26.687 :  INFO : ${elementCount} = 0
```

Any help further down the road would be much appreciated as well.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this line: `${elementCount}=    Execute Javascript    return document.querySelectorAll('a').length`. Aren't the links in an iframe?

Comment: No, there is no iframe there. Its literally ```<body><ul><li>::marker<a></a><br><em></em></li>``` with a load of li-elements if i look at the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was not lying in the code but instead of the page which was viewed - it gave a 401 so i had something other to challenge first.

As the lower part didnt work as well, here what worked for me:

```
Click Àll Links
    Set Variable    ${i}    0
    ${elementCount}=    Execute Javascript    return document.querySelectorAll('a').length-1
    FOR    ${i}   IN RANGE    ${elementCount}
        Execute Javascript    i='${i}'
        Execute Javascript    document.getElementsByTagName('a')[${i}].click();
        Sleep    0.5s
        Wait Until Element Is Visible    css=a
        ${title_var}    Get Window Titles
        #Select Window    title=${title_var}[${i+1}]
        Log    ${title_var}[${i+1}]
        #SeleniumLibrary.Capture Page Screenshot
        Sleep    0.5s
        Select Window    title=${title_var}[0]
        Exit For Loop If    ${i} == ${elementCount}
    END
    Log    Exited
``
```